# Explain what I did hear in the TV?

Tags: atoms, neutrons

I heard in the TV that the **`invention of the neutron was very dangerous and with it, we were able to hit the heart of the atom to destroy it to make explosion`**.

Like I really don't understand that, so, do they mean like if we send the Earth planet to the Sun, will make the sun explode.

I would appreciate if you start with a basic explanation, please.

Please, make the bombings of Hiroshima exclusive.

Comment: Discovery not invention.

Comment: Don't know why **`put on hold`**  @Allure, he does get it and he answered my question. Good luck in your journey for putting questions on hold. @Qmechanic

Comment: @SolarMike, you mean the solar system is discovered. Hmm, well I agree with you, you are right. I found this after typing so I'm going still typing

Comment: It is the use of "invention" in this "*invention of the neutron*"...

Comment: @SolarMike Exactly true.

Comment: So you suggest the neutron was invented... oh well...

Comment: @Noajm IsMy Name Your question could be put more simply. For example, "How can hitting the centre of an atom with a neutron cause an explosion?". I would remove the part about the earth hitting the sun as it is wrong.

Comment: @rghome  I would do that I like that, hopefully not going to be duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most atoms are composed of three things: protons, neutrons, and electrons. Protons and electrons are electrically charged, while neutrons are not. Like charges repel (so protons repel one another), but unlike charges attract (so protons attract electrons and vice versa). The protons and neutrons make up the atomic nuclei, while electrons orbit outside.

Because protons are repelled from one another, we cannot easily shoot protons at another atomic nuclei. They will bounce back. As a result, there are two obvious ways to hit the heart of another atomic nuclei:

1. Make the proton go really, really fast. This is what particle accelerators do.
2. Use something that isn't charged, like the neutron. Because neutrons aren't charged they'll approach the nucleus without being repelled. They can then interact and destroy it.

For some nuclei, adding a neutron to it releases energy. It actually releases a lot of energy (by $E = mc^2$). That's what causes the "explosion" and is a guiding principle behind nuclear fission weapons.

If we send the Earth into the Sun, the Sun is not going to explode. See this [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/402383/what-would-happen-if-jupiter-collided-with-the-sun). The explanation is technical, but the bottom line is that not much will happen.

Comment: Very informative for me.