# Would a human body flying into the sun extend or decrease the time the sun is undergoing fusion?

Tags: sun, stars, fusion, matter

Obviously 1 human body is... nothing compared to the sun, so if the question is easier to answer with 1 million, 1 billion, the entire human population that has passed away in history... the amount isn't as important as the result of adding the matter contained in a human to the sun.

It's a hypothetical based on 'What would happen if cremation via sun was the preferred "burial" method for deceased people?' - Would the sun go supernova sooner or later?

Or is it negligible no matter how many if it's one at a time?

Or is it even negligible if millions/billions/trillions were 'added' at once?

Comment: Possible duplicate, on a much grander scale: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/402383/44126

Comment: Thanks for the link for the read, interesting either way but I think the difference in chemical composition *may* be important? Asking because I don't know though.. And certainly think the difference in mass would be relevant. Even all the humans on earth right now (highest population in history) we wouldn't match the mass of Jupiter, right?

Comment: @rob Though this one line in the second to top answer *may* answer my question "They also mention that the mass would make the sun last longer, which is suspect, since extra mass typically reduces the lifetime of main sequence stars." I wouldn't mind more details on typical vs atypical interactions and why that is though

Comment: One fact that surprises my astronomy students is that the Sun contains more than 99% of the mass of the solar system. A second fact that surprises them is that Jupiter contains more than half of what's left — that is, Jupiter is more massive than all of the other planets, minor planets, comets, etc. combined. Total human biomass is likewise a negligible part of the mass of the Earth. The answer to your question is the answer to the Jupiter question, but dialed way back.

Comment: It's actually a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/402899/